# ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound with ajax destroy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

I'm currently working on a rails app with ajax and the destroy function does not work properly as I keep encountering an `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in ItemsController#destroy` error.

For additional information I can delete the item just fine but the ajax part isn't functioning and the item will only disappear when I refresh the page.

I can't seem to pinpoint on what could be main source of the problem and I currently need some help.

Thanks in advance!

items_controller.rb

```
    class ItemsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    @item = current_user.items.build(item_params)
    if @item.save
        flash[:notice] = "Item was saved"
        redirect_to user_path(current_user)
    else
        flash[:error] = "There was an error saving the item. Please try again"
        render :new

    end
  end

  def destroy
    @items = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @items.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Item was removed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted.try again!"
    end
  end

     respond_to do |format|
     format.html
     format.js
   end

  def new
    @item = Item.new
  end

  private

  def item_params
    params.require(:item).permit(:name)
  end

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:show]

    def new
        @user = User.new
    end


    def show
   @user = params[:id].nil? ? current_user : User.find(params[:id])
    @items = @user.items
    end

   def update
    if current_user.update_attributes(user_params)
      flash[:notice] = "User information updated"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
    else
      flash[:error] = "Invalid user information"
      redirect_to edit_user_registration_path
        end
    end


   private

   def user_params
     params.require(:user).permit(:name)
   end
 end
```

_item.html.erb

```
 <p id="items-<%= item.id %>">
    <%= link_to "", [current_user, item], method: :delete,remote: true, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-ok' %>
    <%= item.name %>
 </p>
```

destroy.js.erb

```
<% if @items.destroyed? %>
   $('#items' +<%= @items.id %>).hide();
 <% else %>
   $('#items' +<%= @items.id %>).prepend("<div class='alert alert-danger'><%= flash[:error] %></div>");
 <% end %>
```

routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do


  devise_for :users
  resources :users, only: [:update, :show, :new, :index]

  resources :users do
    resources :items, only: [:create, :new, :destroy]
  end


   authenticated :user do
 root to: "users#show", as: :authenticated_root, via: :get
end


unauthenticated do
  root 'welcome#index'
end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  def destroy
    @items = Item.find(params[:id])

    if @items.destroy
      flash[:notice] = "Item was removed"
    else
      flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted.try again!"
    end
  end
```

It looks like you are ending your #destroy method before redirecting/rendering anything.

Answer (score 0):

I thought you have to fix your destroy method into this:

```
def destroy
  @items = Item.find(params[:id])

  if @items.destroy
    flash[:notice] = "Item was removed"
  else
    flash[:error] = "Item couldn't be deleted.try again!"
  end
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
  end
end
```

I hope this help you.